# Reference project directory from anywhere

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path, kotlin

I am currently coding a Java/kotlin project in intellij and have to use file readers to get XML and other text based files.

I have made a directory called files for which I store all the files necessary.

The problem I have is that I need to make a new path for each method call to reference the files directory as it is different depending on which directory the method is called from.

Is there a way to reference the project root directory or files directory and have it work everywhere, something like System.getDirectory("files" OR "root") etc.

I am currently using System.getProperty("user.dir") but this path is subjective to where it is being called and is thus not what I am looking for.

Comment: *as it is different depending on which file it is called from*: no, it's not. A relative path is relative to the **current** directory, i.e. the directory from which `java` is executed. If you run from your IDE, this is usually the project root directory, unless you explicitly specify something else in the run configuration.

Comment: `I have made a directory called files`: where exactly did you create that directory? How do you start your project?

Answer (score 1):

If your files are bundled with your application, use resources and load them from the classpath. Otherwise, I recommend adding configuration support or command line parameters to your app to let the caller specify the location of these files. Relying on figuring out the 'current directory' is error prone and subject to the environment (in your case, whichever directory the 'Run Configuration' in Intellij specifies, usually $MODULE_DIR$ in a maven project).